# Couldn't load cocos2dcpp

Tags: android, cocos2d-x

We have a game released in google play with many users playing it.
We keep getting crash reports (not so many) in google play that say that cococs2dcpp could not be loaded. Any idea what might cause it for **some** of the users?
(We have read online that it can be something related to simulators but it seems these crash reports are coming from real users on mobile devices that say in the crash report comment that the game does not open anymore)

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load cocos2dcpp from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.myproduct-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.myproduct-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]]: findLibrary returned null
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:355)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:525)


Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load cocos2dcpp: findLibrary returned null
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:429)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:554)
```

So far it is reported from these devices

- Galaxy Note 8.0 (konawifi)
- Xperia SP (C5303)
- Xperia V (LT25i)
- nuclear-jw9a702
- Galaxy S2 Plus (s2vep)
- Galaxy Note 8.0 (kona3g)
- Galaxy S Stratosphere (SCH-I405)

Comment: `UnsatisfiedLinkError` means either you have provided incorrect library name or you haven't yet build native library correctly, may be device you are running have different architecture like `x86 or mips`

Comment: Thanks. Please check my devices list

Comment: Just looking at listed device model can not guaranty what is the actual problem. Did you tried building with `APP_ABI:=all` in your `Application.mk` file?

Answer (score 6):

You need to run the command line script from the `proj.android` folder - `python build_native.py`. This generates the library you're missing.

Comment: it's saying no such file or directory. please help on this , i m getting same error